# carousel_slider showing only one image

Tags: flutter, dart

I have to explain a bit the current structure:

news_view.dart has got FutureBuilder and fetching all necessary items from API and sending to another page Widget: **customListTile3(articles, index, context)**

hallo.dart has got above Widget:

```
Widget customListTile3(List<Datum> articles, int index, BuildContext context) {
  final urlImages = [
    articles[index].imageUrl!,
    
  ];
  final urlImage = urlImages[index];
```

and

```
child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                options: CarouselOptions(height: 200),
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
                  return buildImage(urlImage, index);
                },
              ),
```

bottom there is buildImage class:

```
child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                options: CarouselOptions(height: 200),
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
                  return buildImage(urlImage, index);
                },
              ),
```

Slider works but it show only single image with multiple times. What  is problem here?

Comment: There is no buildImage  class. Please mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

You are only returning a single image in your function. Passing an index into a list would give you a single element at that particular index.

```
  final urlImages = [
    articles[index].imageUrl!,
    
  ];
  final urlImage = urlImages; //remove [index];
```

Comment: return buildImage(urlImage, index); The argument type 'List<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Comment: Please provide the full code as the provided code isn't sufficient for finding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved:

```
final urlImages = [
    articles[0].imageUrl!,
    articles[1].imageUrl!,
    articles[2].imageUrl!,
    articles[3].imageUrl!,
    articles[4].imageUrl!,
    articles[5].imageUrl!,
    articles[6].imageUrl!,
    articles[7].imageUrl!,
    articles[8].imageUrl!,
    articles[9].imageUrl!,
  ];
```

```
Center(
              child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                options: CarouselOptions(
                
                ),
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (context, idx, realIndex) {
                  return buildImage(articles, urlImages[idx], idx, context);
                },
              ),
            ),
```